# What is the optimal way to localize Firebase error.localizedDescription?

Tags: firebase, error-handling, swiftui, localization

Im able to localize Firebase errors but i'm pretty sure I'm not using the optimal way.

I use AuthErrorCode extension with NSLocalizedString and strings in my Localizable.strings files :

```
extension AuthErrorCode {
    var errorMessage: String {
        switch self {
           case .missingEmail:
                return NSLocalizedString("FBEmailMissing", comment: "")
...
```

View:

```
...

@State var AuthErrorCodeString: AuthErrorCode?

...
                        FirebaseSession_VM.resetPassword(email : email) { (result) in
                            switch result {
                                case .failure(let error):
                                    
                                    // on va trapper les erreurs ici!!!!
                                    // errString = error.localizedDescription
                                    AuthErrorCodeString = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code)
                                case .success(_):
                                    break
                            }
...

                .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Password Reset"),
                          message: Text(AuthErrorCodeString?.errorMessage ?? "Success. Reset email sent successfully. check your email"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
                            if AuthErrorCodeString?.errorMessage == nil {
                                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            }
                          })
                }
```

Localizable.strings (English)

```
"FBEmailMissing" = "Email is missing!!!";
```

Localizable.strings (French)

```
"FBEmailMissing" = "Courriel manquant!!!";
```

My code is working but i want to use the optimal way. What's your suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I don't think that there is a better way